# How to display posted XML data in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, xml, post

I am trying to setup a test page that will display an XML Post from a gateway but can not find any examples of how to do this. Every example I have seen has been posting information FROM a page or reading an XML FILE but nothing relating to dispalying a (I think its called) xml stream that is posted to a page?

The idea is this: User submits a form.  Form is posted to gateway.  Gateway responds with success/failure and error messages (in the form of xml) to my dev page.  Dev page displays the XML.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

if it's for development purpose, you could use the firebug plug-in for Firefox instead of having the "Dev page displays the XML"

http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: It would need to be a page that displays the results since the gateway will repond with an xml post with the details of errors and such that the developer will need to look at.

I am going to be testing with the following code.  It should work from what I can tell but since it takes an hour or two to get a response some the people running the test its hard to tell:

Comment: [code]
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' create xmldocument instance 
        Dim myXmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
        myXmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = True

        ' load xml via stream, rather than file, by using Request.InputStream
        myXmlDoc.Load(Request.InputStream)

        'Write the XML onto the browser
        'Response.Write("do it!")
        Response.Write(myXmlDoc.InnerXml)
    End Sub
[/code]

Comment: When you say: "It should work from what I can tell but since it takes an hour or two to get a response some the people running the test its hard to tell".  I don't understand, why can't you just post to the page yourself to test it??